# Dart: How to fix the condition?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

I'm a newbie. I create an angular application using the IDEA template and insert the code from the example:

```
<p *ngIf="true">
    Expression is true and ngIf is true.
    This paragraph is in the DOM.
</p>
```

An error occurs:

> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Starting Build [INFO] Updating asset graph completed, took 16ms
>   [SEVERE] angular on lib/app_component.dart: Template parse errors:
>   line 6, column 4 of AppComponent: ParseErrorLevel.FATAL: Can't bind to
>   'ngIf' since it isn't an input of any bound directive. Please check
>   that the spelling is correct, and that the intended directive is
>   included in the host component's list of directives.  
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ [INFO] Running build completed, took 650ms [INFO] Caching
>   finalized dependency graph completed, took 853ms [SEVERE]
>   build_web_compilers|entrypoint on web/main.dart (cached): Unable to
>   find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of either a
>   bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a
>   dev_dependency needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure
>   (if importing a generated file).
>
> Please check the following imports:
>
> `import 'package:untitled1/app_component.template.dart' as ng;` from
>   untitled1|web/main.dart at 2:1
>
> [SEVERE] build_web_compilers|entrypoint on test/app_test.dart
>   (cached): Unable to find modules for some sources, this is usually the
>   result of either a bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or
>   possibly a dev_dependency needs to move to a real dependency), or a
>   build failure (if importing a generated file).
>
> Please check the following imports:
>
> `import 'package:untitled1/app_component.template.dart' as ng;` from
>   untitled1|test/app_test.dart at 5:1
>
> [SEVERE] build_web_compilers|entrypoint on
>   test/app_test.dart.browser_test.dart (cached): Unable to find modules
>   for some sources, this is usually the result of either a bad import, a
>   missing dependency in a package (or possibly a dev_dependency needs to
>   move to a real dependency), or a build failure (if importing a
>   generated file).
>
> Please check the following imports:
>
> `import 'package:untitled1/app_component.template.dart' as ng;` from
>   untitled1|test/app_test.dart at 5:1
>
> [SEVERE] Failed after 1.6s

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to list directives you use in the template in the `@Component()` annotation

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart'

...

@Component(
  selector: 'foo-bar',
  templateUrl: 'foo_bar.html',
  directives: [coreDirectives /* or NgIf */],
)
```